# Swift Generic function call another Generic function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am using Swift 2.2 on XCode 7.3.1 and trying to call a `Generic` function from another `Generic` function.

**Code**

```
class Thing1 {
     let variable: SomeProtocol
     init<A: SomeProtocol>(variable: A) {
          self.variable = variable
          self.add1(self.variable)
     }

     func add1<A: SomeProtocol>(stuff: A) {
          let thing: Thing2 = Thing2()
          thing.add2(stuff)
     }

}

class Thing2 {
    func add2<A: SomeProtocol>(stuff: A) {

    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol { }


add1("a") // Cannot invoke 'add1' with an argument list of type '(String)'
add1(4) // Cannot invoke 'add1' with an argument list of type '(Int)'
```

I get the error.

```
'Cannot invoke add with an argument of list type '(Whatever type I used to call the function)''
```

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little bit. In a playground it compiles fine but when you try and call 'add1' it doesn't let you.

Comment: @CodyWeaver Can you please post a minimal example that's as close to compiling as you can get? This way, we're all testing consistently, without having to come up with our own implementations of `SomeProtocol`, `Thing`, etc.

Comment: Added the code to make it more clear what is going on.

Comment: @CodyWeaver Have you conformed the types that you wish to have access to `add1` to `SomeProtocol`? E.g. `extension String : SomeProtocol { }` and  `extension Int : SomeProtocol { }`.

Comment: Yeah I added the extensions. I also added way more code to show more of the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [abstract types in Swift don't necessarily conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – therefore you cannot use a `SomeProtocol` typed thing as a concrete typed thing that conforms to `SomeProtocol` (which is what your `add1` generic function expects as an argument).

The simplest solution in your case therefore is just to use the generic `variable` argument, rather than the `variable` property, as because it's a generic, it's typed as a concrete thing that conforms to `SomeProtocol`, which can therefore be passed into your `add1` function:

```
init<A: SomeProtocol>(variable: A) {
    self.variable = variable
    add1(variable)
}
```

However in order to prevent these kind of issues later down the line, you may want to consider making your class generic, assuming that your `variable` property should be of constant type throughout the lifetime of a given `Thing1` instance:

```
class Thing1<A:SomeProtocol> {

    let variable: A

    init(variable: A) {
        self.variable = variable
        add1(variable)
    }

    func add1(stuff: A) {
        let thing = Thing2()
        thing.add2(stuff)
    }
}
```

Or, you could refactor your code to use the abstract type `SomeProtocol`, which will allow you to work with *any* type that conforms to `SomeProtocol` (e.g allowing you to mix different `Thing1` instances with different `variable` types in an array):

```
class Thing1 {

    let variable: SomeProtocol

    init(variable: SomeProtocol) {
        self.variable = variable
        add1(variable)
    }

    func add1(stuff: SomeProtocol) {
        let thing = Thing2()
        thing.add2(stuff)
    }
}

class Thing2 {
    func add2(stuff: SomeProtocol) {

    }
}
```

Although you should always be aware of the extra costs that come with using abstract types, [see this great WWDC talk for more info](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the extensions to `String` and `Int` and constructing `Thing1` objects makes it work:

```
extension String: SomeProtocol{}
extension Int: SomeProtocol{}

Thing1(variable: "a").add1("a")
Thing1(variable: 2).add1(4)
```